# Is it possible to make this image in CSS?

Tags: html, image, css, css-animations

I was working on something in photoshop. You can see the picture here: 
[image]

The three triangles in the background refer to 3 different pages on my website. I was wondering if it was possible to put the images like this in CSS because I want them to work like links and put some simple zoom animation on it when you hover on it. I'm actually pretty noob and new to CSS in overall so this will be hard to make without doing a lot of research but I hope you guys can help me out and give me a way to start. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

just to be clear, the 3 triangles should become 3 individual pictures. I'm forced to work with flexbox on school if that matters. Thanks again.

Comment: Just take this image and make it into an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

Comment: I'd suggest to make this image in SVG: it's made of relatively simple vector shapes, and you can use the regular `<a>` tag inside SVG to make its parts clickable/

Comment: The triangles are pretty simple to make in CSS I would say. Just make a square, rotate it, and add a gradient with a transparency to it (I can go into detail with this if you want, as you're new to CSS).

Comment: I'd appreciate it! @Maharkus

Comment: is it possible ? Maybe. have you tried to solve it ? Maybe not

Comment: People need to be reminded that CSS is not a graphics drawing program. On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a rough draft of how I would create this in CSS. Basically I made three squares (`.triangle` to `.triangle3`), gave them a rotation (`transform: rotate(45deg);`) and added a gradient with a transparency (`background-image: linear-gradient( to top left, red, transparent 50%);`) to each of the squares. This creates the basic triangular shape, as the other halves of the squares are hidden if they are big enough to go over the viewport. I positioned the elements next to each other by using `position: absolute;`.

I did not use flexbox however, but I don't think flexbox would be the right thing to use in this case.

Another thing to point out: If you don't want the 45° angles you can also use `transform:skew`. It skews the element and gives you the possibility to create different angles. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew) is a good resource for this.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  position: relative;
  width: 475px;
}

.triangle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 255, 0, 1), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.triangle2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0));
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.triangle3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-image: linear-gradient( to top left, red, transparent 50%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0% auto;
}

.wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle2"></div>
<div class="triangle3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help all of you, I'll try this out and let you guys know how it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

You can play with gradient, shadow and mix-blend-mode , but the best and most efficient is SVG.
example to start with if you feel like spending hours drawing your shapes .

```css
.img {
  float:left;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at bottom center, transparent 20%, black 90%),
    linear-gradient( 50deg, rgba(125, 60, 213, 0.7) 32%, transparent 32.5% ),
    linear-gradient(-50deg, rgba(0, 108, 179, 0.7) 32%, transparent 32.5%) #000;
  min-width:400px;
}
.img:before {/* to keep ratio*/
  content:'';
  float:left;
  padding-top:66.66%;
}
.img:after {/* to draw stars spots */
  content:'';
  display:block;
  height:2px;
  width:2px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow: 50px 10px 1px  white, 55px 11px 1px  white, 45px 12px 1px  white, 40px 25px 1px  white;
}
.moon {
  float:left;
  margin:10% 1%;
  width:9%;
  padding-top:9%;
  box-shadow:0.30em 0.30em 0 0.25em gold ;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.star {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  width: 2.5%;
  padding-top:1.25%;
  margin:3em;
  transform:rotate(-20deg);
}
.star:before , .star:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(247, 237, 135),gold);
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  transform:skew(50deg) rotate(10deg)
}
.star:after {  
  transform:skew(-50deg) rotate(50deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <b class="moon"></b>
  <b class="star"></b>
</div>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should not be answering these questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help all of you, I'll try this out and let you guys know how it worked out! Thanks for your time and giving me some examples!

Comment: @Rob I'm not asking people to write code, I'm asking people how I should do it in the best way to make this possible. If some nice people are willing to help me to start, than I appreciate that. I can learn from this. So I don't know what your problem is here.

Comment: @LucasVerhoest I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937)

Comment: @rob, that' s an example, not usable as it is but good enough to let the op dig into it or decide to turn on SVG, which is the main advice here ...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image (or single elements) in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) with a tool like this: https://www.base64-image.de/

[image]

It is one of the oldest ways to encode things into html (first proposed in 1987!). It is a way of turning different types of data into a series of letters and numbers that is safe for HTML. One of those data types is images.

I can't paste a sample code here because it's too long.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a div container which will contain the image of the background background and then you just add div you position inside thanks to the position: absolute; using the top, bottom, right, left.
Like this :

```css
.container {
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bUXt.png");
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
   }
.triangle1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
.triangle2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:50px;
}
.triangle3 {
  position:absolute;
  top:300px;
  left:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle1">
      <img src="https://alexanderssteak.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/starfav.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="triangle2">
      <img src="https://alexanderssteak.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/starfav.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="triangle3">
      <img src="https://alexanderssteak.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/starfav.png" alt="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. That's not what SO is for. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer